# Numpy merge two arrays can i make a numpy array like this?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying two array like this. It's different from column_stack so I am not able to find how to do it from documentation or google search.

I have arrays `a` and `b`. How can I make `c` from them ?

```
a = [[1, 2],[3, 4]]
b = [[5 , 6]]

c = [[[1, 2],[5]],
     [3, 4],[6]]]
```

I need this to input the values to theanets.

Comment: I think you're missing a square bracket; should it be `[[3, 4],[6]]]` on the last line? In any case `c` looks like a ragged array and so it will have the `object` dtype. If you're working with numerical values you'll lose a lot of the benefits of regular NumPy arrays by doing this.

Comment: You can get each element with `for x in [0,1]: a[x] + [[b[0][x]]]` but I'm new to Python and will try to wrap this in a new array.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with arrays and numpy? This question does not seem to be about numpy at all.

Comment: Your 'array' display looks like nested lists.  But you mention column_stack and tag with numpy.  This is impossible in numpy without making `C` a `dtype=object` array.  What, exactly, does `theanets` require?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [54]:
a = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
a
Out[54]:
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [55]:
b = np.array([[5 , 6]])
b
Out[55]:
array([[5, 6]])


In [96]:
c = [[a[n].tolist() , b[:,n].tolist()] for n in range(len(a))]
c
Out[96]:
[[[1, 2], [5]], [[3, 4], [6]]]
```

Comment: If `a` and `b` are lists to start with, then this variation does the trick: `c = [[a[n], [b[0][n]]] for n in range(2)]`.

Comment: You're right it seems to be the same logic actually , except I'm just converting array into lists in order to get result in shape